# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/

Tags: java, android

Looking for some help on an error I am getting while trying to store Pictures taken with the camera for an App I am trying to develop. The error is

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/JPEG20161108_153704_

The logcat points to this method in my code at the line where FileProvider.getUriForFile is being called..

```
private void dispatchTakePhoto() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivity(takePictureIntent); // this worked originally
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, ""+e);
            }
            if (photoFile != null) {
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(TallyActivity2.this,
                        "com.example.bigdaddy.pipelinepipetally.fileprovider", photoFile);
                takePictureIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is used to create the image file

```
 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        /* Create an image file name */
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsoluteFile(), imageFileName);
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        /* Tried this also, not working. Leaving for debugging.
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,
                ".jpg",
                storageDir
        );*/

        File image = new File(path, imageFileName);
        try {
            /* Making sure the Pictures directory exist.*/
            path.mkdir();
            storageDir.createNewFile();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents */
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Here is the `onActivityResult()` method, where I am wanting to save the image captured to a class with the saveImage() method and also setting the thumbnail to an `ImageView`. The saveImage() method returns a byte so I can pass the byte in a Bundle through an Intent to another full screen activity, where it will be displayed, should the user click on the thumbnail `ImageView`.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        /* If it's equal to my REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE var, we are all good. */
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            /*Saving to the Pipe class with the saveImage() method below.*/
            sDummyImagePicByte = saveImage(imageBitmap);
            /* Going ahead an setting the thumbnail here for the picture taken*/
            mPipePicImage.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            Log.i(TAG,Arrays.toString(sDummyImagePicByte)+" after assignment from saveImage()");
        }
    }
```

Here is the `Manifest.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.example.bigdaddy.pipelinepipetally">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedDebugMode">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TallyActivity2"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".JobAndDbActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ExistingTallyActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ImageToFullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.bigdaddy.pipelinepipetally.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths">
            </meta-data>
        </provider>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is the `file_paths.xml` file that I created and put in the app/res/xml/ folder (which I created also). Not sure if this is the correct location (for the folder).

```
<paths >
    <files-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>
    ...
</paths>
```

Also this is the `onRequestPermissionsResult()`

```
 @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA:
                /* if request is canceled, the result arrays are empty */
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    /* Permissions granted so the mPermissionIsGranted boolean is set to true*/
                    mPermissionIsGranted = true;
                } else {
                    /*
                    Permissions denied so the mPermissionIsGranted boolean stays false here and
                    providing a Toast message to the user, letting them know that camera permissions
                    are required for this feature.
                    */
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Camera permissions required\nfor this" +
                                    "feature.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /* Continuing to hold the false setting to this boolean since not granted.*/
                    mPermissionIsGranted = false;
                }
                break;
            /* For accessing and writing to the SD card*/
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SD_CARD:
                /* if request is canceled, the result arrays are empty */
                if(grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    /* Permissions granted so the mPermissionIsGranted boolean is set to true*/
                    mPermissionIsGranted = true;
                } else  {
                    /*
                    Permissions denied so the mPermissionIsGranted boolean stays false here and
                    providing a Toast message to the user, letting them know that camera permissions
                    are required for this feature.
                    */
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SD Card permissions required\nfor this"+
                                    "feature.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    /* Continuing to hold the false setting to this boolean since not granted.*/
                    mPermissionIsGranted = false;
                }
                break;
            /* For the GPS location permissions.*/
            default: MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
            /* Still to be implemented .*/
                break;
        }
    }
```

I sure appreciate any help on this. I am still new and learning Android. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

I use to have boilerplate code for all of the paths for File provider. You will never get such type of errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path name="external" path="." />
  <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
  <cache-path name="cache" path="." />
  <external-cache-path name="external_cache" path="." />
  <files-path name="files" path="." />
</paths>
```

For more details, You can check [FileProvider - Specifying available Files](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider#SpecifyFiles)

Comment: Still having the issue. The folder path is `/Download/`

Comment: How to fix the folder path is /Download/?

Answer (score 14):

Its little late.. but i finally able to solved.

As per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html):  `The path component only corresponds to the path that is returned by getExternalFilesDir() when called with Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES.`

so use

`getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`

instead of

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
```

and your path should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="InstructiveRide" path="Android/data/com.package.ride/files/Pictures"/>
</paths>
```

and write this if you have a subdirectory under Picture directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="InstructiveRide" path="Android/data/com.package.ride/files/Pictures/InstructiveRide/"/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? It's the only one that worked...

Comment: Thank you! Your documentation is better than Google's....

Answer (score 5):

```
<files-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>
```

This points to a `files/` directory inside of `getFilesDir()`. However, that is not where `createImageFile()` is looking to place the file. Instead, it is using `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. You need to:

1. Decide which location is the correct one (or choose another option than either of those), then
2. Synchronize the implementations

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the files-path in the XML file is pointing to the Internal files storage?

Comment: @J2112O: Correct. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html#SpecifyFiles).

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare , so @J2112O need to change `<files-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>` to `<external-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>` ? _files/_ path is correct? something more to change?

Comment: @Jaco: `<external-path>` does not map to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`. There is nothing directly in `FileProvider` that maps to `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`.

Comment: I see @CommonsWare , thank you! So @J2112O need to use `getFilesDir()` instead of `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DI‌​RECTORY_PICTURES)`, using the `files/` path. As you said on this community, there is a documentation bug, right? https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html  thank you!

Comment: @Jaco: Switching to `getFilesDir()` would be simplest. You can try to hack an `<external-path>` to point to `DIRECTORY_PICTURES`, but I fear that it will be unreliable. The `<external-path>` documentation bug was fixed a few months ago.

Comment: What will be the answer? Using `<files-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>` or?

Comment: I am also stuck on this problem, did you get a fix yet? I have tried `getFilesDir() ` and `<files-path name="my_images" path="files/"/>` to no avail.

Answer (score 5):

I am also trying to upgrade my application to avoid FileUriExposedException. I wanted to achieve the same that was mentioned in the actual question.  I managed to work with
    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)

Only trick is use following path

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

I got this hint from following blog.

https://proandroiddev.com/sharing-files-though-intents-are-you-ready-for-nougat-70f7e9294a0b

I spent few hours to figure out. I hope It would safe someone time.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I defined a suffix for my application id in the `build.gradle` file for `debug` mode, and when I ran the application in the debug mode, the package name did not compatible with what I mentioned in the code. It is better to set the applicationId(packagename) variable in your `xml` and `java` code.

for doing this in your menifest for your provider set :

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
```

and in your java code :

```
Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+".fileprovider",
```

and for your provider path create two different files for different build variants(release and debug)

for release :

```
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.android.example/files/Pictures" />
```

and for debug:

```
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.android.example.debug/files/Pictures" />
```