# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains Nested files in assets folder

Tags: android, illegalargumentexception, android-assets, android-fileprovider

I need to share pdf files from my assets folder.
The pdf file changes based on language.

Assets structure is  like -

```
  assets
      folder
         countryA
                   languageA
                             pdfA
                   languageB
                             pdfB
         countryB
                   languageA
                             pdfA
                   languageC
                             pdfC
```

My Android manifest file -

```
 <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
```

When the following code runs

```
FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
    new File("String file name"));
```

I am getting a  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains` `/file:/android_asset/folder/countryA/languageA/file.pdf`

I believe it is because the path in the provider xml is not configured.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="my_file_name" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I have used *files-path* as the files are under assets folder.
Since the files are nested how do i configure the provider path.

I have consulted the following links

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516126/fileprovider-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root)

[Link2](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0)

[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498380/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-failed-to-find-configured-root-that-contains)

Comment: `FileProvider` doesn't support assets, out of the box. You could [roll your own `ContentProvider` that does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5888718), use an existing solution – like CommonsWare's [`StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) – or copy the files out of assets to storage before using `FileProvider`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Content providers worked for this use case. Sharing worked using Bluetooth, mail but fails in case of Gmail app. I am working on that. Will share the solution once done.